# use map or list types in cequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cequel

I'm trying to define a Box class in Rails 5 with Cassandra and Cequel.
is there a way to define a column with the map type.

something like this

```
create table Box ( id int PRIMARY KEY, coordinates Map<text, int>)
```

is there a way to do this with Cequel in rails?
ideally something like

```
class Box
    include Cequel::Record
    column :coordinates, :map
```

or if there are some other more preferred way of storing coordinates or list information feel free to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

For a regular type like `text` or string you'd do:

`column :name, :text`

For a map - Cassandra needs to know the datatype for the key and value you are going to insert. Try:

`map :coordinates, :<key_type>, :<val_type>`